# When deploying a GeoServer via Docker the container can't see my data directory

Tags: postgis, geoserver, docker, directory

Deploying a GeoServer via Docker (include data with PostGIS). Container can't see my data directory. I am use Ubuntu 20.04

I need the GeoServer through docker to show my data, which I copy to COPY ./data_dir/* usr/share/geoserver/data_dir. But only a few folders are added in the docker, although the image itself weighs 20 GB, like my data. Everything works through the terminal.

```
# my Dockerfile 

FROM postgres:12
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes postgresql-12-postgis-3 postgresql-3-postgis-3-scripts postgresql-contrib


FROM ubuntu

Update the sources list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y apt-transport-https

Get the JRE/JDK installation
RUN apt-get install -y default-jre default-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jdk
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
Install basic applications
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential wget unzip
RUN apt install -y wget 
RUN apt install -y nano 
RUN apt-get install unzip

Get GeoServer and add USER
ENV GEOSERVER_HOME=/usr/share/geoserver
RUN mkdir $GEOSERVER_HOME
RUN useradd -m -U -s /bin/false user
RUN chown -R user $GEOSERVER_HOME
RUN cd $GEOSERVER_HOME

WORKDIR $GEOSERVER_HOME

RUN wget -c -q https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.23.x/geoserver-2.23.x-latest-bin.zip --no-check-certificate
RUN unzip geoserver-2.23.x-latest-bin.zip -d $GEOSERVER_HOME
RUN rm geoserver-2.23.x-latest-bin.zip

add data_dir
RUN chown -R user ./data_dir

COPY ./data_dir/* /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir
RUN echo "export GEOSERVER_HOME=/usr/share/geoserver" >> ~/.profile
RUN . ~/.profile
RUN echo "export GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN . ~/.bashrc


RUN GEOSERVER_LIB_DIR=$GEOSERVER_HOME/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/
COPY web.xml /usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml

WORKDIR $GEOSERVER_HOME/bin

COPY *.sh $GEOSERVER_HOME/bin
RUN chmod +x $GEOSERVER_HOME/bin/*.sh 
EXPOSE 8081 
CMD ["bash"]
ENTRYPOINT $GEOSERVER_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

Comment: where does GeoServer think the data directory is? That should help you work out which bits aren't working

Comment: when I start the container, on the geoserver page directory = /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir

Comment: and is that directory empty? or the default? or your data?

Comment: This directory include default data or show empty. I am add data directory in VOLUME and I also add my data directory  in File sharing. But when I run docker compose this Image, it only sees 4 folders from my directory. Maybe you need to somehow add the schemas that are stored in  PostgreSql.

Comment: Have you looked at the .env variable RECREATE_DATADIR?  Maybe add this to your Docker Compose?    RECREATE_DATADIR=FALSE.

Comment: Then the layer view shows 0.

Comment: Seems like you may need to create a Docker Volume.  I'm using an older version, but my Dockerfile has VOLUME ["${GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR}"].  With ENV \ GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir

Comment: I am try, but don't work.